# PHP send HTTP 200 ok response and if any error found/success, send that response afterwords. Is this possible in PHP?

Tags: php, api, http, timeout

My code requires sending a `200` ok response to a client that sends json data to my API code within 100 seconds.

My code has a long process of cloning assets, creating texts to be stored in tokens, and other processes, which takes a lot of time, hence the platform sends a timeout request alert, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

So how, if possible, in PHP can I send the code `200` response telling the platform that the API has successfully received the valid json and then after processing the request json send out any errors or success messages. My code lives on windows server and most of the time I run this API code via Postman to test/configure etc.

Comment: http_response_code(200); ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you need to coordinate this with the API client (the sender of the initial JSON).  When you 200OK, they are likely to close and proceed as if all went well.  Look at **[AS2 - application statement 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS2)**. That implements what you are looking for (delayed message disposition notices), but not trivial.  Best course is to try to do it all in a single request-response http session.

Comment: The sender of the JSON mentioned that they only expect 200 status code response to their triggered request to my API, what my concern is that the later processes if some error occurs, would that be a normal process of echoing those errors or successful completion? All I want is to API client receive the status code and later on the remaining lines of codes run as they should

Answer (score 0):

1) make it go faster (really, 100 seconds to handle a single request is ridiculous) When you say "cloning assets" are we talking about DNA here?

2) handle the processing asynchronously - the first request submits a task for processing and returns a reference to the client, the client can then poll the state poll the task later.

3) Fully validate the client data and the ability of the server to service the request and make a response, then do the work (BTW this sucks as a solution)

Answer (score -1):

**Yes it is possible in php
you can set response code in header.**

Comment: good comment, but not an answer. Please refrain , wait till you have enough rep to post comments on OP's question.

Comment: We can use this     header("HTTP/1.1 503 Not Found");